# how to make the links in the navigation bar to show through opacity navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

I have managed to change the opacity of the navigation bar to 0 by adding this java script line

**strong text**

> ```
>  $(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
>     $('.navbar-1').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / 500)); 
>     });
> ```

it's all good now but i want the links to keep showing even though the link navigation bar is at 0 opacity.

how can i achieve that?

Comment: `child` can not have `higher` opacity than `parent`..

Comment: so is there a way to achieve this? i have seen many websites that have utilized this technique.